# Get value of node using xmlpath.v2 golang

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, go

I am parsing a xml document using [gopkg.in/xmlpath.v2](http://gopkg.in/xmlpath.v2), and I am finding a trouble... I have no problem to get info from a single node, or get a iterator and loop over its items getting their info. But, the case where I am blocked is when I try to get the info from the same node on which I am iterating. I think that an example will be illuminating.
This is the XML:

```
<Warnings>
    <Warning Type="309" ShortText="Unfulfilled Paid Service 1">Unable to book seat 1</Warning>
    <Warning Type="309" ShortText="Unfulfilled Paid Service 2">Unable to book seat 2</Warning>
    <Warning Type="309" ShortText="Unfulfilled Paid Service 3">Unable to book seat 3</Warning>
</Warnings>
```

These are the xpath that I am usin:

```
xpath := xPathWarning{
    WarningsBase:       "Warnings/Warning",
    Warning:            "",
    WarningAttr:        "@ShortText",
}
```

And this is the way that I am trying to get the value and attribute:

```
func getWarnings(root *xmlpath.Node, xpath xpath_OC) []Warning {
    warnings := []Warning{}
    v, _ := xmlpath.Compile(xpath.WarningsBase)
    WarningsBaseIter := v.Iter(root)
    for WarningsBaseIter.Next() {
        rawOffer := WarningsBaseIter.Node()
        warning := Warning{
            Value: GetString("", xpath.Warning, rawOffer),
            Attr:  GetString("", xpath.WarningAttr, rawOffer),
        }
        warnings = append(warnings, warning)
    }
    return warnings
}
func GetString(ExpressionPrefix string, XPathExpression string, Node *xmlpath.Node) string {
    Expr := []string{ExpressionPrefix, XPathExpression}
    pathString := strings.Join(Expr, "")
    if pathString != "BLANK" {
        Path, err := xmlpath.Compile(pathString)
        if err == nil {
            Value, _ := Path.String(Node)
            return Value
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

I am able to get the ShortText, but not the value. I had been checking the error, showing on terminal the result of `Path, err := xmlpath.Compile(pathString)`, and the err shown is `compiling xml path "":0: empty path`.

Any solution for this??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[xmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/xmlquery) package supports extract data from XML by XPath expression.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/antchfx/xmlquery"
)

func main() {
    xmlStr := `<?xml version="1.0"?><Warnings><Warning Type="309" ShortText="Unfulfilled Paid Service 1">Unable to book seat 1</Warning></Warnings>`
    doc, _ := xmlquery.Parse(strings.NewReader(xmlStr))
    nodes := xmlquery.Find(doc, "//Warning")
    for _, node := range nodes {
        fmt.Println(node.SelectAttr("ShortText"))
        fmt.Println(node.InnerText)
    }
}
```